# How to compare strings of two pandas column using fuzzywuzzy module

Tags: python, pandas, fuzzywuzzy

I have a dataframe with multiple columns i want to compare two columns to each other. I tried to use fuzzywuzzy module than create function and than apply it on column

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools
import re
import pymorphy2 
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords 
import difflib
import fuzzywuzzy as fuz
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz 
from fuzzywuzzy import process

def stringComparison(column1,column2):
score = fuzz.WRatio(column1,column2)
return score

df1['Коэффициент  схожести'] = df1['Условие показа'].apply(stringComparison(df1['Условие показа'], df1['Поисковой запрос']) but i get invalid syntax error 

File "<ipython-input-2-b03e1cc77905>", line 1 df1['Коэффициент схожести']df1['Коэффициент схожести'] = df1['Условие показа'].apply(stringComparison(df1['Условие показа'], df1['Поисковой запрос']) ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What i am doing wrong

Comment: `df[...]df[...]` is a syntax error. What is this supposed to mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming your intention is to apply StringComparison to the columns 'Условие показа' and 'Поисковой запрос' to create 'Коэффициент  схожести'

```
df1['Коэффициент схожести'] = df1.apply(lambda x: stringComparison(x['Поисковой запрос'],x['Условие показа']), axis = 1 )
```

Your current issues are;

1. The left hand side of your last line of code is nonsense.
2. When applied to a series the apply method applies the supplied function
   to each row of that series. But you only have access to the data contained within that particular series. not any data from other column in the dataframe. In your case it is not using any row information at all and would instead take the whole of `df1['Условие показа']` and `df1['Поисковой запрос']` as inputs to the `stringComparison` function.

Comment: When i aplly lambda function i get KeyError: ('Поисковой запрос', occured at index 0')

Comment: does the column 'Поисковой запрос' exist in df1?

Comment: Yes, it is exist in df1

Comment: hmm don't know what to tell you then. this works fine for me (dont have fuzzy quzzy installed but see edit)

Comment: So sorry, i had mispelling in column name. Now its work.